# How to add multiple text values to appbar Flutter

Tags: flutter, appbar, flutter-appbar

I am new to flutter and would like to create an app bar with 2 different text values, please see below:

[image]

So far, I have written the following code:

```
    class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final double toolbarOpacity = 2.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:
      PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size(double.infinity, 114),
        child: AppBar(
          centerTitle: false,
          title: Text(
            'My App',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: titleTextColor,
                fontWeight: titleTextFontWeight,
                fontFamily: titleFontFamily,
                fontSize: titleFontSize),
          ),
           backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(232, 232, 242, 1),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Which has given me the following results:

[image]

Could somebody please either direct me to material or help me to achieve my desired output?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As title accepts widget u can use column widget in it like this

```
AppBar(
          centerTitle: false,
          title: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                'My App',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: titleTextColor,
                    fontWeight: titleTextFontWeight,
                    fontFamily: titleFontFamily,
                    fontSize: titleFontSize),
              ),
              Text("My second text"),
            ]
           )
           backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(232, 232, 242, 1),
        ),
```

u can use PreferredSize to defined size

```
appBar:
      PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size(double.infinity, 114),
        child: AppBar(
          centerTitle: false,
          title: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                'My App',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: titleTextColor,
                    fontWeight: titleTextFontWeight,
                    fontFamily: titleFontFamily,
                    fontSize: titleFontSize),
              ),
              Text("My second text"),
            ]
           )
           backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(232, 232, 242, 1),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried placing a Column widget as title with two children being two Text widget like this ( I can't test the code right now but it should be something like this ) :

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final double toolbarOpacity = 2.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:
      PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size(double.infinity, 114),
        child: AppBar(
          centerTitle: false,
          title: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                'My App',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: titleTextColor,
                    fontWeight: titleTextFontWeight,
                    fontFamily: titleFontFamily,
                    fontSize: titleFontSize),
              ),
              Text("My second text"),
            ]
           )
           backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(232, 232, 242, 1),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I had experimented with the Column widget but I was placing it in the wrong part of my code. Thanks very much for the prompt, accurate response.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor:Colors.amber,
        appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size(double.infinity, 114),
            child: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Color(0xfff7f7fb),
              flexibleSpace: Padding(
                  padding:EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child:Column( 
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(height:20),
                    Text("Monday 3rd August 2020",
                        style:
                            TextStyle(color: Color(0xff59595a), fontSize: 15)),
                    Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                            alignment:Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text("My App",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black, fontSize: 25))))
                  ])
                  ),
            )),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello World'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can see live preview at : [enter link description here](https://codeapprun.io/sachindarde/widget/czHANSQNtq)

[image]